# Connections between Posets and WQO's

Tags: combinatorics, relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Here is the question that I [posted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25314783#25314783) on the [Mathematics Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) that I was unable to find an answer to:

> **Question:** Under what conditions/properties is a **poset** ever a **wqo (well-quasi-order)**? Can we find a definition for **wqo** involving **posets**?

---

### Background Definitions

**Definition [Partially-Ordered(-Set)].** *Let $A$ be a set. Then $\preceq$ on $A$ is partially-ordered $\iff\preceq$ is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric.*

**Definition [Well-Quasi-Ordered(-Set)].** *Let $A$ be a set. Then $\preceq$ on $A$ is wqo $\iff$ every infinite sequence of elements of $A$ is good $\iff\exists \ i,j\in\mathbb{Z}:i<j$ and $a_i\preceq a_j$ of the infinite sequence $(a_i)_{i\geq1}$.*

**Definition (Well-Founded).** *$\preceq$ is well-founded $\iff\not\exists$ any infinite decreasing chains w.r.t. $\prec$.*

(Note: $x\prec y\iff x\preceq y$ and $y\not\preceq x$.)

---

### My Thoughts

By the definitions, I was thinking that essentially we can say that a wqo is essentially a **poset that is well-founded**. I say this statement because the fact the a wqo makes for a strict, monotonic order such that $i$ is strictly less than $j$ ($i<j$) with a preorder $a_i\preceq a_j$, we can see that defining a well-foundedness on a poset would restrict infinite decreasing chains and will mostly likely make the poset good and possibly a wqo.

---

### Final Comments

1. Please **feel free** to let me know if I have anything **errors** in my definitions or explanations/thoughts pertaining to the content solely from this question.
2. If you also think this question is better suited on **MathOverflow**, please let me know.

Comment: You’re missing part of the definition of a wqo: it must be a quasi-order, meaning that it must be reflexive and transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing part of the definition of a wqo: it must be a quasi-order, meaning that it must be reflexive and transitive. Equivalently, $\preceq$ is a wqo on $A$ iff it is a well-founded quasi-order with no infinite antichain. This means that a partial order with an infinite antichain is not a wqo even if it’s well-founded. For example, the order $\preceq$ on $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ given by $\langle k,\ell\rangle\preceq\langle m,n\rangle$ iff $k=m$ and $\ell\le n$ is a well-founded partial order that is not a wqo.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering) is actually fairly helpful.

Comment: Then how can we relate posets and wqo's directly? When is a wpo a wqo; when there is no infinite antichain?

Comment: @Julian: Neither class is included in the other. A partial order must be antisymmetric, so not every wqo is a partial order, but a wqo must not have any infinite antichains, so not every partial order is a wqo. A well partial order is an antisymmetric wqo.

Comment: Alright. So then can we say that a well-ordering is essentially in close proximity of a wqo?

Comment: @Julian: I don’t know what you mean by *in close proximity* here. Every well-order *is* a wqo, but a wqo, or even a well partial order, can look quite different from a well-order.

Comment: Ok. I see now, Thank you.

Comment: @Julian: You’re welcome.

Comment: Actually, just out of curiosity, can we say that a poset X is a well-quasi-order (w.q.o) if is it well-founded and every
   anti-chain is finite?

Comment: @Yes: that follows immediately from the alternative definition in my answer.